# mp4 movies are not displayed in IE

Tags: video.js

I am using video.js to play mp4 video files.

It works fine in Chrome & Safari, but not in IE
Here is a link for a sample page:

http://www.shafan.co.il/gsPedia/Templates/Shafan/DisplayItem_NEW.asp?WordID=4485&Word=&CategoryID=143

The page is in Hebrew... Sorry... But you can clearly see where the video box is...

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

check out the source on [http://videojs.com/](line 92). their video works in ie. i played a little with the plugin on localhost, and came across the same issue... try setting up the video plugin manualy (by running js code after video tag), as they did on their homepage (line 99). chears.